# Define function only if something is true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is a simplified version of my code :

```
window.onload=function(){
    var url = document.URL;
      if(url.indexOf('someurl')) {
        var function1=function(){
          ...
        }
      }
      else if(url.indexOf('someotherurl')) {
        var function2=function(){
           ... 
         }
      }
```

My problem is that if I'm on the `someotherurl`, I'll just get an error in the body of `function1` and if I'm on `someurl`, I'll get an error in the body of the `function2`..How can I stop this from happening?
I use this code in a chrome extension content script.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: After I get the url, I split it and the error is that I can't use method split on undefined

Comment: You should probably use a single variable and only change its value in the if statement.

Comment: That error probably has nothing to do with the way you're declaring the functions. You should show the actual code and the actual error.

Comment: I just got my answer..It was a bug because even if I was on the someotherurl, url.indexOf() returned -1 and that is still true..so function1 was executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because url.indexOf('someurl') evaluates to -1 if not found and if(-1) is true.

Change your code to:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var url = document.URL;
      if(url.indexOf('someurl') > 0) {
        var function1=function(){
          ...
        }
      }
      else if(url.indexOf('someotherurl') > 0) {
        var function2=function(){
           ... 
         }
      }
```

Comment: Ohh..Dumb me :))..I forgot that I get -1 in return if there is no url.indexOf()...Thanks :D

Comment: Strictly speaking, depending on what those strings really are, the test should be `>= 0` and not `> 0`.